# Junit5 Mockito @InjecctMocks not working with MockMvc

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, junit5

MockMvc calling the controller but unable to creating @Autowired objects in controller class:
AuthControllerTest.java

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class AuthControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @InjectMocks
    private AuthController authController;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(authController)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    void getToken() throws Exception{
        mockMvc.perform(post("/auth/token")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content("{\"username\" : \"Santa Clause\", \"password\" : \"1223\" }")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.status").value("Success"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.result").exists())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.result.username").exists())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.result.token").exists())
                .andDo(print());
    }
}
```

AuthController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController extends ContextService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthController.class);

    @Autowired
    IAuthManagement authManagement;

    @PostMapping("/token")
    public ResponseEntity getToken(@RequestBody AuthenticationDTO data) throws UserException {
        logger.info("\nCreating a new Token for user from credentials passed. *** "+data.getUsername()+"-->"+data.getPassword()+"-->"+authManagement);
        return authManagement.getToken(data);
    }
```

Output:

```
Creating a new Token for user from credentials passed. *** Santa Clause-->1223-->null
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:72)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
```

@InjectMocks is not injecting anything because authManagement is null and hence the nullPointerException.
Can anyone please help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mock `IAuthManagement authManagement;`

In your test class add something like this..

```
@Mock
IAuthManagement authManagement;
```

In addition to this you'll have to mock your service method too. 
https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/unit-testing-of-spring-mvc-controllers-normal-controllers/

In the above tutorial take a look at the test class, line 50, you'll have to do something like.. `when()`  so that it won't return null

Comment: Now the controller layer is working but the service layer is returning null.

Comment: @Rick: I think you're mixing different concepts together. Either you want to use `spring` to setup your depencies (aka `IntegrationTest`) or you use `mockito` to mock the dependencies away (aka `UnitTest`).

Comment: I've edited my answer to include one more step to do.